# how do i validate jquery dialog controls generated dynamically from the gridview

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, c#-4.0, jquery-dialog

i have a asp:gridview in which there is multiple data. i have a template field in the gridview that opens a jquery modal dialog. My template field and my Jquery dialog Code :

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <a href="#" onclick="linkbtnTest('<%# "#"+Eval("LCID")%>')">Add Shipment Status</a>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbltest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LCID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <div id='<%# Eval("LCID") %>' style="display: none; margin-top: 90px; margin-left: 90px;">
                                    <table id="tbl_LCStatus_dialog" align="center" border="0px">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="height: 20px; width: 30px;">
                                                Invoice Number<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server"
                                                    ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="valShip" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtInvoiceNumber"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>

                                            <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-left: 20px;">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInvoiceNumber" runat="server" CssClass="td_records"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>


                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitShipment" runat="server" Text="Submit" CommandName="Select"
                                                    ValidationGroup="valShip" OnCommand="btnSubmitShipment_Command" CssClass="btnSubmitCSS"
                                                    CausesValidation="True" />
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnResetShipmentRecord" runat="server" Text="Reset" CssClass="btnSubmitCSS" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

When i click on the data of the 2nd Row in gridview to open a modal dialog, the ID that asp.net generated is **ContentPlaceHolder1_gvdLCStatus_txtInvoiceNumber_1** .

Now i want to validate the data of the jquery modal dialog no matter how many items are present in the gridview and what so ever id it may generate.

Comment: can you be more specific about what is not working or what you want to achieve.

Comment: my validation, it only happens when the 1st row of the gridview is clicked and the dialog appears.